# How Do you Set up Mandrill to work with KeystoneJS

Tags: node.js, express, mandrill, keystonejs

For a newbie to Node and Keystone, the documentation for configuring Mandrill within my keystone JS app is not sufficient enough for me to get the email form working (this is most likely due to my limited experience).

Within my current keystone.js file I have the code included below. I added my `MANDRILL_API_KEY` to the .env file. For reference the App I create is just the boilerplate Keystone app that the generator creates with Handlebars as the template engine. My current effort did not result in the email form sending email as expected. I'm struggling to figure this out as there doesn't appear to be much on the web that goes into detail on how to set this up.

The documentation for Keystone indicates you can do the following and it will default to the .env variables set. I also tried including these two lines of code with the environment variables set and Mandrill still didn't work. I would greatly appreciate any help someone can provide helping me to get this configured. Thank you.

```
keystone.set('mandrill api key', 'your-key');
keystone.set('mandrill username', 'your-username');
```

Current keystone.js file

```
keystone.init({
'name': 'myApp',
'brand': 'My App',

'less': 'public',
'static': 'public',
'favicon': 'public/favicon.ico',
'views': 'templates/views',
'view engine': 'hbs',

'custom engine': handlebars.create({
    layoutsDir: 'templates/views/layouts',
    partialsDir: 'templates/views/partials',
    defaultLayout: 'default',
    helpers: new require('./templates/views/helpers')(),
    extname: '.hbs'
 }).engine,

'emails': 'templates/emails',

'auto update': true,
'session': true,
'auth': true,
'user model': 'User',
'cookie secret': 'J/x|3n&#SHG)OS1"pOTPk0/TA;[*[2HMK(vUX]HrfEym&`P]CX>oP50eWeD{Cz2e',
'mandrill api key': process.env.MANDRILL_API_KEY
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file (make one if it doesn't exist in the project folder next to keystone.js) you need to place :
    
# MANDRILL key for email sending
    
MANDRILL_API_KEY=
    
MANDRILL_USERNAME=

Comment: I have the .env file setup and had it previoulsy setup. I seem to have a problem initializing it or setting the Mandrill info with the keystone.js file. Can you provide any additional thoughts on whether I am on the right track with my keystone.js file or do I need to do something different.

Comment: Just set them as environment variables. Edit your `/etc/environment` or provide on the command line `MANDRILL_API_KEY ='a' MANDRILL_USERNAME ='b' node keystone.js`. To confirm this echo in your keystone.js file `console.log(process.env.MANDRILL_USERNAME)`. As long as these are set before `keystone.start` is executed you should be good.